# problems with emit event in child component

Tags: vue.js

I still don't understand how emit event, which show my component-one (child). I know I do something wrong, but don't know exactly what. One-component should be hide. Then after click should show. Any help?

parent component

```
<template lang="pug">
        one-component(v-on:welcome="weAreHere") 
</template>

export default {
  name: "Playlist",
  data () {
    return { }

   },
component: {
   one-component
},
 methods: {
    weAreHere() {
        console.log("here we are!")
    }
}
```

one-component

```
<template>
  .mainBox1
    button.burgerMenu(v-on:click="$emit('welcome')")

   export default {
     name: "one-component",
     data () {
           return {
             show: true,
                 }
      },
```

Comment: If you want to hide one-component , you dont need any emit event just change your show data as `this.show= false`

Comment: I've added more detail and examples to my answer below. Mostly you just need to add a method back to your child component to do the emit.

Comment: Please see a similar question that helped me fix a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789767/laravel-9-problem-emitting-event-from-child-component-to-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit where you added the method to the parent, you removed the method from the child. You still need a method in the child to use $emit. And you need one in the parent if you want it to react to the signal with the console.log().

I don't use pug, and didn't try to run this code, but the idea should be clear enough to make it work.

parent-component

```
<template lang="pug">
  child-component(v-on:signal="weAreHere") 
</template>

export default {
  name: "Playlist",
  data () {
    return { }

  },
component: {
  child-component
},
methods: {
  weAreHere() {
    console.log("here we are!")
  }
}
...
```

child-component

```
<template>
  .mainBox1
    button.burgerMenu(v-on:click="signalParent")
</template>

export default {
  name: "child-component",
  data () {},
  methods: {
    signalParent() {
      this.$emit('signal')
    }
  }
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I see your confusion. You're attempting to reference the child component's method from the parent. You have a child component using emit to contact the parent which you expect to call the method in the child. You should call the child method in the child component. You don't need to emit anything.

Use `$emit` when you want the parent to do something.

For example:

Parent

```
<template>
     <ChildComponent v-on:signal="myMethod"/>
</template>

<script>
     methods: {
          myMethod() {
               //do something in parent after emit from child
          }
     }
</script>
```

In child:

```
someMethod () {
     this.$emit('signal')
}
```

When the parent receives 'signal', they will call `myMethod`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. One more question: this `someMethod` in child I should call this method on the click elemet? `button.burgerMenu(@click="someMethod")'

Comment: So I changed the code as you suggestioned, but I still don't have a console.log :/ Can you look at, is tere is still some mistakes? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Are you checking the browser console and not the IDE console? If you'd like, I can make a CodePen for you with the code to demonstrate.

Comment: It wouldbe great :)